# Cant mock axios api call with axios-mock-adapter in Storybook with Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, axios, storybook, axios-mock-adapter

Been trying to use storybook with my VueJS project and Im stuck with mocking api calls.
I tried using axios-mock-adapter without luck.

My storybook file code is:

```
import { storiesOf } from '@storybook/vue';
import { action } from '@storybook/addon-actions';
import { withKnobs, boolean } from '@storybook/addon-knobs';
import axios from 'axios';
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';
import fileUpload from './fileUpload.vue';

const mock = new MockAdapter(axios);

mock
  .onPost('https://s3.amazonaws.com')
  .reply(200, []);

storiesOf('Common|File CSV Upload', module)
  .addDecorator(withKnobs)
  .add('Default', () => ({
    components: { fileUpload },
    data: () => ({
    }),
    template: ` 
        <v-flex>
            <file-upload></file-upload>
       </v-flex>`,
    methods: {
      action: action('file upload'),
    },
  }));
```

Am I using it right?

Answer (score 0):

My strong recommendation is to use **storybook-addon-mock** for mocking (axios) API calls in Storybook.

It is **nicley integrated** into Storybook, setup in the different stories is easy and the data can be alteresd in the corresponding panel.

**These 4 steps are needed**:

1. Add the additional **dependency**: `yarn add storybook-addon-mock`
2. **adapt the config** and add in `.storybook/main.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  addons: [
    ...
    'storybook-addon-mock',
  ],
```

3. **configure the behaviour** and add **mock data for general**/ repeating API calls in `.storybook/preview.js`. These are mocks that will be available in every story.

```
export const parameters: Parameters = {
  mockAddonConfigs: {
    globalMockData: [
      {
        url: 'api/token',
        method: 'POST',
        status: 200,
        response: () => '1234567abcdefg',
      },
    ],
    refreshStoryOnUpdate: true, // This re-render the story if there's any data changes
    // disable: true, // This disables the panel from all the stories
  }
```

4. in your **story file** add:

```
export default {
  title: 'components/myComponentName',
  component: MyComponent,
  parameters: {
    mockData: [
      {
        url: '/api/myendpoint/',
        method: 'GET',
        status: 200,
        delay: 500,
        response: () => 'some content',
      },
      {
        url: '/api/myendpoint/',
        method: 'POST',
        status: 200,
        delay: 1000,
        response: {
          data: 'some response',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
```

Hint: Have a look into the different responses - function, string, etc to match them with the real response. There can be a pitfall with the `data` entry, that can be avoided with `response: () => 'some content'`